why does "sudo echo 1 > /sys/module/vfio/parameters/enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode" give permission denied in dpdk vfio-pci driver?
modprobe vfio enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode=1

image 1
image 2
image 3
image 4
dpdk version 21.11 and pcap++ is the latest version
thank you in advance!
